# Data not fetching with custom url axios ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

i am new in Reactjs and working on nextjs,I have following components (components/Trending.js)
which is working with this url "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" but whenever i changed url(My custom url which contaning api data) to "https://90d9-2405-201-5002-215b-6c7b-1f41-7a19-f145.in.ngrok.io/serges/api/blogs" then records is not fetching,Here is my code (components/Trending.js)

```
import React from 'react';
class Trending extends React.Component {
    state = {
        trending: []
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://90d9-2405-201-5002-215b-6c7b-1f41-7a19-f145.in.ngrok.io/serges/api/blogs',
        )
          .then(res => {
            const trending = res.data;
            this.setState({ trending });
          })
      }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <table className="table table-hover">
              {this.state.trending.map((post, index) => {
                 return (
                      <tr>
                      <td>
                          <h4>{post.name}</h4>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                  )
              })}
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Trending;
  import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: First of all, import should be on top of the file, right below `import React from 'react`

Comment: try (JSON.stringify(response.data)), unless you don't get error for the get request

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import Axios at the top of the file.

Comment: done but still not working, problem with "url" (whenever changed existing url to my custom url )

Comment: Did you check you network panel, if the request is success or there is some error?

Comment: can you check console.log(trending) and  tell what you are seeing in log  ???
or can you check you network tab when you calling the api?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your browser's console and Network tab. Most probably it's the [CORS issue](https://blog.container-solutions.com/a-guide-to-solving-those-mystifying-cors-issues)

Comment: then how can i solve this ?

Comment: CORS can be only solved on a server side. Or create a proxy

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue. You should fix it on the server-side. Add the front-end application URL in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header. For local development, you can create a proxy server.

Comment: it means if i working on server then we will give access/permission to specific url (my website url) , am i right ?

Comment: Yes correct @Amit